# Imagenes tipo BLOB almacenadas en una tabla

Tags: php, blob

Alguien sabe como extraer imagenes tipo BLOB almacenada en una tabla MySQL y convertirlas a .png, para almacenarlas en una carpeta?

El siguiente código extrae la imagen del campo "200x150" de la tabla "img_alq" y la muestra en pantalla:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png"); 

if(isset($_GET['id'])){   
    $id = $_GET['id']; 

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("ERROR AL CONECTAR"); 
    $db_select = mysql_select_db('claromec_restore') or die ("ERROR al seleccionar la BD");

    $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM `img_alq` 
                    WHERE `idalq` = $id
                    ORDER BY `idalq` ASC, `orden` ASC, `id` ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die ("Error al consultar"); 


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo $row["200x150"]; 
    } 


    mysql_free_result($result); 
    } else { 
        echo 'NO hay ID'; 
 } 

?>
```

Comment: No... no intente nada porque no se me ocurre como hacerlo y no encuentro nada al respecto, si puedo, almacenar en BLOB, leer e imprimir las imagenes... pero ni idea de como reconvertirlas nuevamente a .jpg o .png.

Comment: ok, sigo tu consejo y añado ese codigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mostrar una imagen que fue guardada como BLOB

#### 1. Mostrar directamente como resultado de la petición

Al haber sido guardada en su formato original, sólo es necesario mostrarla como resultado de la petición:

```php
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $imagen = $row["200x150"];

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $imagen;


    die(); //No debería haber más salida
}
```

- Nótese que sólo se muestra una única imagen, por lo que no corresponde hacer un bucle en los resultados de la consulta a la base.

#### 2. Mostrar dentro de un HTML

Se puede mostrar dentro de una etiqueta `<img>`, codificada en base 64.

```php
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php 
    echo base64_encode( $imagen ); 
?>" />
```

#### 3. Convertir o manipular la imagen antes de mostrarla

Para el manejo de imágenes en PHP, las funciones [GD](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.image.php) ofrecen una solución inmediata para lo que necesites.

En este caso, [**imagecreatefromstring()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)
genera un recurso de imagen, que luego podemos convertir, modificar como se quiera, o guardar en un archivo nuevo.

```php
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $imagen = $row["200x150"];

    //Crear el recurso de imagen desde un string binario
    $imagenGD = imagecreatefromstring( $imagen );

    if ( $imagenGD ) {
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        //Mostrar como PNG
        imagepng( $imagenGD );
    } else {
        //Error con la imagen
    }
    imagedestroy( $imagenGD ); //liberar el recurso
}
```

- Si en vez de mostrar la imagen como resultado de la petición HTTP, quisieras guardarla en un archivo nuevo, sería pasando la ruta como segundo parámetro:

  ```php
  imagepng( $imagenGD, $nombreArchivo );
  ```

Comment: Respecto al comentario: "Nótese que sólo se muestra una única imagen, por lo que no corresponde hacer un bucle en los resultados de la consulta a la base.", hay alguna forma de mostrar todas las imágenes que se obtuvieron en la lectura?. Porque, si puedo mostrarlas con un buche armaría un Carousel para poder mostrarlas.

Comment: @RicardoPastuszek Sí, pero en ese caso, el resultado de tu PHP sería un HTML y no una imagen, por lo que podrías utilizar el método 2 de esta respuesta. En los métodos 1 y 3, el resultado de todo el script es una única imagen... O simplemente se podría generar un HTML con el enlace para mostrar la imagen desde otro script. Por ejemplo imprimiendo con `echo '<img src="http://tuweb.com/mostrarImagen.php?id=' . $row['idalq'] . '">';` ... Y luego mostrando cada imagen desde ese otro script (mostrarImagen.php).